# How to add Readme file in visual studio web installer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, installation

How can we add  readme files in web installers created using visual studio.After installing the product,readme file's path should be shown in control panel.

Comment: By showing up in control panel i mean if anything gets installer in add remove program section we can see it's name,publisher,Installdate,version etc.here we can also see readme.Actually path of the readme file get's displayed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily add a readme by creating it and putting it in the applications `contents` by finding the `text file` within `solutions explorer`, right clicking and then going to `properties`.

In the properties change `build action` to `content` and I'm assuming you'd want `copy if newer` selected on `copy to output folder`

from here simply go into the `file system` of your `Installer project`, go to `application folder` then right click on a blank space in the applications folder `panel, add, project output` and finally `content files`

this will put your text file inside the folder where it is installed on your client machine, I'm presuming you've already made the text file, if not simply create one by right clicking your project, add item, general tab and then text file.

*EDIT*

thankyou for the reply, 
Rigt click your project, then choose properties and select the `application` tab you can change all the information by clicking `Assembly Information...`

*EDIT 2*

Theres a microsoft application called bizTalk that will do most of it all for you, there's a link with more information here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561017.aspx

*EDIT 3*

The best I can do after a lot of searching is to give you a path that will open a folder for you to place your readme into?

If you want to do that and tinker to see whether this path can be edited, then inside the file system of the installer, right click and press `add special folder`, then Custom Folder, name it what you like, something like ReadMeFolder? then right click and go to its properties change the DefaultLocation to whatever you like, but give it a property of ARPREADME, from here as soon as you've built and installed it, the folder path for this will be under the "readme" tab in your add and remove programs, there will be a way to change this so that it can target a file, Again I'll do a little more searching to see if i can make it open the file instead of the containing folder

Also have a mess around with making folders properties being ARP.... because the ARP stands for add remove program and its here that you can make the folder to certain things to do with the control panels Add & remove programs.

Comment: By showing up in control panel i mean if anything gets installer in add remove program section we can see it's name,publisher,Installdate,version etc.here we can also see readme.Actually path of the readme file get's displayed here.

Comment: using Biztalk seems to be a much easier process, Sorry I couldn't help any more than that!

Comment: I've almost got it now, sorry about the hassle, ignore what I've put about the readme, I've just placed a link inside add and remove programs and im just experimenting as at the moment it only opens the directory that contains the read me

Comment: I've now updated my answer to as far as I've got, will get back to you if I can set link as the txt not just the containing folder

Comment: I have tried the edit3 part.But I am not successfull.I have created a custom folder named it as read me.I made AlwaysCreate property true,edfault location as [targetdir] property as appreadme,transitive false.Aaftr building whien i run the installer even this readme folder will not get created.PLease help

Comment: did you make it APPREADME?  its   A R PREADME, it stands for Add/Remove Programs Readme?
The folder doesn't get created however unless you change the location, TargetDir just makes it go to the applications folder

Comment: I have tried with both appreadme as well as arpreadme.but not successfull

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11981/discussion-between-shipu-and-alex)